# Определить что аудио прошло два круга

Tags: c#, unity3d

Стоит задача, сменить музыку после того как аудиофайл завершится два раза, т.е. пройдет два круга, как правильно это определить? 
Я начал корутиной, после того как завершится аудио, срабатывает итератор, только вот он срабатывает один раз, когда музыка заканчивается во второй раз, итератор не реагирует.

```
private IEnumerator WaitMusicPlayinsSecond()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds ( _gameOnject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.length);
    currentIteratorClipLengt++;
    }
```

Comment: audio.PlayOneShot(MyAudio);  audio.PlayOneShot(MyAudio); <- Сделать так не вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private IEnumerator WaitMusicPlayinsSecond()
    {
        AudioSource audioSource = _gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        YieldInstruction yi = new WaitForSeconds(audioSource.clip.length);
        while (currentIteratorClipLengt < 2)
        {
            yield return yi;
            currentIteratorClipLengt++;
        }
        audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }
```